# How to detect user interaction in a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

hello all i want to track the action when the user add a new chips to run a save function

Html :

```
<md-chips ng-model="contacts" md-autocomplete-snap="">
    <md-autocomplete
      md-selected-item="selectedItem" 
      md-search-text="searchText" 
      md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)" 
      md-item-text="item.name" 
      placeholder="Specify your reviewer(s)">

        <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.name}} {{item.email}}</span>
    </md-autocomplete>
    <md-chip-template>
        <span>
            {{$chip.email || $chip}}<br>
        </span>
    </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

JS :

```
$scope.$watch('contacts', function(){
    if ($scope.chip){
        alert("hello")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use md-on-append

```
   <md-chips md-on-append="newEmail($chip)"... >
```

https://github.com/angular/material/tree/master/src/components/chips/demoBasicUsage

Answer (score 0):

`ng-change` will do the trick. You can add this :

```
ng-change="yourFunction()"
```

And then in your controller

```
$scope.yourFunction = function(){
   if ($scope.chip){
      alert("hello")
   }
 }
```

With that, each time your value in your `ng-model` will change, this function will be call.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i used the ng-change on the md-chips but it dosen't work